When the chainlink node is started, an error occurs in the database
I deployed and started an evm private chain (unsynchronized main chain) node using the besu project, then followed the chainlink official tutorial, started postgresql using docker, and the chainlink container.When a chainlink container is started, the postgresql container log displays an error message, as shown in the following figure:
cl-postgres-1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
cl-postgres-1  | 
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.215 CST [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.14 (Debian 14.14-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.216 CST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.216 CST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.303 CST [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.469 CST [61] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-12-02 17:22:28 CST
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:28.550 CST [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.250 CST [68] ERROR:  relation "ocr2_oracle_specs" does not exist at character 22
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.250 CST [68] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ocr2_oracle_specs WHERE plugin_type = 'mercury'
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.372 CST [69] ERROR:  relation "node_versions" does not exist at character 21
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.372 CST [69] STATEMENT:  SELECT version FROM node_versions ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.375 CST [69] ERROR:  relation "goose_migrations" does not exist at character 32
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.375 CST [69] STATEMENT:  SELECT tstamp, is_applied FROM goose_migrations WHERE version_id=$1 ORDER BY tstamp DESC LIMIT 1
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.533 CST [69] ERROR:  relation "migrations" does not exist at character 16
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:22:43.533 CST [69] STATEMENT:  SELECT id FROM migrations


cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:24:18.059 CST [69] WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
cl-postgres-1  | 2024-12-02 17:24:18.191 CST [69] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress

